# check for empty gridview row C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

How to check for empty gridview row. I have tried the following

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
     if(i=0 &&
       (Label)gvMaster.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("dealer_name").Text!="" && 
       gvMaster.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("dealer_name") !=null)
        {
          // do something
        }

 }
```

I have getting an error stating that System.Web.UI.control does not contain definition for text.

How to check if the row exists and is empty or null?

Thanks

Comment: check "dealer_name" maybe letters are wrong!Check FindControl result as well.

Comment: what is type of dealer_name

Answer (score 0):

**This:**

```
if(i=0 && (Label)gvMaster.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("dealer_name").
Text!="" &&   gvMaster.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("dealer_name") !=null)
```

**Should be This:**

```
if((i==0) && (gvMaster.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("dealer_name") !=null  &&   
(((Label)gvMaster.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("dealer_name")).Text  
.ToString().Trim()!=""))
```

**Explanation :**

1.for comparing values you should use `==` instead of single `=`.
2.You have to `Cast` the `Control` before reading the property values, Cast the `Control` as `Label`.
3.`Trim` the values before comparing `strings` for avoiding white space problems.
4.first do a null check before accessing the `Control` properties, because if control is not found it `throws` an `Exception`